# Can't edit or delete xlam add-in

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I have an xlam that is shared with me and several coworkers. I wanted to edit or even just delete the add-in. But when I go to save the edits it reads "xxx.xlam is read-only." I unchecked the read-only box in the properties box, but it still gives me the same message.

When I go to delete the whole file it reads "The action can't be complete because the file is open in Microsoft Excel" I am the only here so I know no other coworker has it open.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A couple things to try

1. To remove the Add-in, go to you Developer Tab > select Excel Add-Ins > uncheck the add-in
2. To edit the Add-in, you will probably have to have to open the add-in and re-save it as not read only. To do this, select the workbook in the properties window of your VB editor. Look for the `IsAddin` property and set it to `False`. This will open up the .xlam file like its a normal excel workbook. Next, save as the file into you Add-ins path (`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIn`) making sure it's not set to read only. Now go back and reset the `IsAddin` property to `True` and you should be able to edit and save the add-in. My favorite way to save the Add-in is to select the add-in workbook object in the properties window, then type `ThisWorkbook.Save` into my immediate window and press enter.
3. To delete the add-in, try to follow step 2 where you set the `IsAddin` property to `False` then exit out of the Add-in file that pop's up. Next, close the workbook, go to `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIn` and delete the add-in from the folder.

Hopefully this helps. If not [here is a good link.](https://www.contextures.com/exceladdins.html)